# Why does this AWS Lambda report that it didn't complete when it finished with no errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

When I invoke my AWS Lambda via the CLI, it succeeds/finishes and doesn't show any errors .. but it also suggests that it didn't complete?

```
C:>> dotnet lambda invoke-function Renewals
Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET Core applications (5.6.6)
Project Home: https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli, https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet

Payload:
{"Id":1,"Status":1,"IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":false,"IsCompletedSuccessfully":false,"CreationOptions":0,"IsFaulted":false}

Log Tail:
START RequestId: 87fe3754-811f-4526-83a4-<snip> Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 87fe3754-811f-4526-83a4-<snip>
REPORT RequestId: 87fe3754-811f-4526-83a4-<snip>  Duration: 1653.84 ms    Billed Duration: 2136 ms        Memory Size: 256 MB     Max Memory Used: 88 MB  Init Duration: 481.83 ms
```

Notice these key/values:

```
"IsCompleted":false,
"IsCompletedSuccessfully":false
```

The function is a .NET7 function and it's an async handler that returns `true`:

```
var handler = new Func<ILambdaContext, Task<int>>(async (ILambdaContext context) =>
{
   // .. logic in here ...

   return true;
}
```

to be honest, it's a function that will end up being triggered by a timer (via EventGrid, I believe) - like a cron job. As such, I wasn't really sure what to return.

Is this right? I'm assuming I've not done something right, here.

Cheers!

Comment: That's from the payload object. Apparently you are passing a payload object into your function invocation that has those values in it. Not sure where those are coming from, but it looks like it came from some sort of test event you are using to test your function. Also, it is "EventBridge", not "EventGrid".

Comment: i really don't understand how? i have not manually set anything in my payload object? refer to the CLI command I entered.

Comment: I'm not a .NET Developer and I've never used that `dotnet` CLI tool before, all I know is that a payload is what is _input_ into the function, not some sort of execution status. And looking at some documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-package-cli.html it appears that the `dotnet` CLI tool logs the payload it is sending to a function invocation. Perhaps you have some sort of default payload file in the directory where you are running the command?

Comment: AH! awesome! while in the AWS GUI under Lambda -> <the function> -> Test -> test it .. the payload is at the bottom, right? so that should be logged instead, then? After i sleep, i'll go and check out if i can see any defaults. even check the source code maybe?

Comment: Again, I don't use those tools you are using, I just know how AWS Lambda works. That Test event you see in the AWS UI would be used when you clicked the "Test" button in the UI. I have no idea if the tools you are using would be going out to Amazon to find that test event and use it as the payload, or if there is some other payload configuration it is using locally.

Comment: Search the handler function for 'Payload' and you should find the code that prints the message.

Comment: My `handler` code doesn't have any variable or instance named `Payload`, let alone me logging/console.writing that.